# When loading KenLM language model for scoring sentences should the LM file size be less than RAM size?

Tags: memory, nlp, language-model, kenlm

When loading language model for scoring sentence should the LM('bible.klm') filesize be less than RAM size?

```
import kenlm

model = kenlm.LanguageModel('bible.klm')
model.score('in the beginning was the word')
```